# Dissapearing A tags on image rotation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a a simple script that, when clicked and draged or swiped 4px, a series of divs become either visible or invisible to create a image rotation effect. Now the funny thing about it is that when i do a full rotation, the first div in the series does not become visible again, it just skips it. Now it really doesnt matter too much cus that last div and the first div are the same image, im just curious on why it does that. Heres the script for the rotation.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $product = $('#product'),
        $imgs = $product.find(".child"),
        imageTotal = $imgs.length - 1,
        clicked = false,
        widthStep = 4,
        currPos,
        currImg = 0,
        lastImg = 0;
    $imgs.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent dragging images
    })
        .filter(':gt(0)').addClass('notseen');

    $product.bind('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
        if (e.type == "touchstart") {
            currPos = window.event.touches[0].pageX;
        } else {
            currPos = e.pageX;
        }
        clicked = true;
        return false;
    });
    $(document)
        .bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
        clicked = false;
    })
        .bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
        if (clicked) {
            var pageX;
            if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                pageX = window.event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
            } else {
                pageX = e.pageX;
            }
            widthStep = 4;
            if (Math.abs(currPos - pageX) >= widthStep) {
                if (currPos - pageX >= widthStep) {
                    currImg++;
                    if (currImg > imageTotal) {
                        currImg = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    currImg--;
                    if (currImg < 1) {
                        currImg = imageTotal;
                    }
                }
                currPos = pageX;
                $imgs.eq(lastImg).addClass('notseen');
                $imgs.eq(currImg).removeClass('notseen');
                lastImg = currImg;
                // $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[options.currImg] + '" />');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (currImg > imageTotal) {
  currImg = 1;
}
```

should probably be

```
if (currImg > imageTotal) {
  currImg = 0;
}
```